# Cordova app crashes when using Chrome DevTools

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, phonegap

I'm creating an app in Cordova for Android, and I'm using Chrome DevTools for debugging. But everytime I use inspect element my app crashes without showing any errors.

It won't happen if I just start DevTools and my app, it will only happen when I use inspect element. I don't have much code yet, only an index file that loads all the JavaScript and CSS files and shows some images for my loading page.

There are no errors showing up in my console either.

Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133
Samsung Galaxy Edge 7
Android 7.0
Cordova 6.5.0

**UPDATE:**
Tested in a newer version of Chrome (58.0.3029.96) and the problem still exists.

**UPDATE:**
I'm using a real device but the problem also exists when using emulated devices through Android Studio.

Comment: We are facing the same issue with a Pixel C Device (Android 7.1.2). The issue popped up during a debug session. One second before it worked as expected, then suddenly it stopped working. The app crashes whenever the debugger is started. There where no updates on the dev machine nor on the pixel C during that session. Even after restart of device and dev machine the issue persists.

Comment: I have the same problem with Redmi 4x (Android 6.0), it was working but after few deployments it stops. I can connect to device, I can see the screen of the app in dev tools but just after that the app crash.

Comment: Closing developer tools and opening new one in new tab resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Any code is there?

Comment: Can you also open logcat and check if you get some error message there?

Comment: @jcubic Agree with Jcesar. Run the application in device and execute the commaon 'adb logcat | grep -i "nameofyourapp" ' in the terminal. you should get the crash log

Comment: @Gandhi I've got crash report in application on my device, it was not normal java stack trace, maybe it was c code that throw error. Can't check it right now because I don't see it anymore. Maybe a bug in chrome.

Comment: Update latest version your phone chrome and try again. Please share chrome DevTools screenshot with console.

Comment: have you changed or played with any of the developer options? try to set them to default

Comment: @AhmadAghazadeh I don't remember but I think I've got standard disconnected  popup like when you deploy again. Will share the error from device when I'll get it again.

Comment: where are you from?Devtools is blocked for some countries like Iran and China.

Comment: @jcubic Hi, did you had a look at this link by any chance - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=562589 This could probably help you out. Probably an issue with the specific device i feel. Also the OP has said its simulated in emulator too. Does she have GPU emulation enabled?

Comment: @Gandhi maybe my problem was different then the OP.

Comment: @Wyannah  Hi, did you had a look at this link by any chance - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=562589 This could probably help you out. Probably an issue with the specific device i feel. You have mentioned its simulated in emulator too. Do you have GPU emulation enabled?

Comment: @jcubic thanks for the response. Since you have set the bounty, I was checking with you to resolve the issue

Comment: @Gandhi I've started a bounty but just after that the problem was resolved and I couldn't undo the bounty.

Comment: @jcubic OK jcubic. Will try out resolving OP's issue

Comment: @Wyannah Any update on this?

Comment: @Gandhi I've updated Android System Webview and I will try again tonight and will post an update as soon as I know if it worked.

Comment: @Wyannah Thanks for the info

Comment: @Gandhi after updating Webview my app hasn't crashed while debugging. I'm hoping this solved the problem for good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the limited information available, I guess the issue could be probably related to the [issue logged in chromium project](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=562589).

As per the chromium issue comments, this could probably be an issue with the device where debugging is done as device is not able to get the latest version of android webview.

The OP has mentioned that the issue happens in emulator too. So probably GPU emulation enabled emulator should resolve the issue.

Comment: By updating Android System Webview as mentioned in the thread you linked it solved my problem. My app hasn't crashed while debugging since then.